# To show dynamic content in bootstrap modal form in PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have included a button to open bootstrap modal form with dynamic heading. If i click the button from any of the item it always showing the first data title.

Ex MySQL table Name - item

```
Id  title   amount
1.  abc     1245
2.  xyz     3344
3.  xxx     4455
4.  zzz     5566
```

In the page i am displaying all the rows from the above table, its working as expected.

Now i need a button to open a bootstrap modal form with dynamic heading for each item, but its always showing the first row heading in the modal form.

**Expected result**

If i click a button for 'xyz' row, currently its showing the heading as 'abc' instead of 'xyz'

**HTML/PHP code**

```
<div class="detail">
<h1 class="project-title">
<a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $row['title]; ?></a>
</h1>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs small text-white mb-2 desktop-img"><a href="" class="text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm"><i class="fa fa-envelope pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Email</a></button>
</div>
```

**Modal form code**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h6 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Enquiry Form</h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <h1 class="project-title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1>

    <div class="md-form mb-1">
          <i class="mt-2 fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
          <input type="text" id="form34" class="ml-2 form-control validate"  placeholder="Your Name">
          <!-- <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form34">Your name</label> -->
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-info">Send <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Bootstrap modals, only the first opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545714/multiple-bootstrap-modals-only-the-first-opens)

Comment: why you use <?php echo $base_url; ?>

Comment: you have to use AJAX for that., where is your AJAX code?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your modals have the same id attribute. You'll need unique IDs for each modal and then specify this ID in the button as well.

**HTML/PHP Code**

```
    <a href="" class="text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm<?= $row['id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Email</a>
```

**Modal Form Code**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm<?= $row['id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true">
        <!--Rest of your modal code -->
    </div>
```

This solution assumes that you have an id field on the rows. If you do not, replace that with whatever unique identifier you have for each row.